# Referring a lookup in validation rule

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I just came across a salesforce documentation to check the limitation of validation rules - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_validation_considerations.htm&language=th

It says:

> Validation Rule Field Restrictions:
>
> Validation rule formulas don’t or can’t refer to:
>
> 1. Compound fields, including addresses, first and last names, and dependent picklists and **lookups**
> 2. Campaign statistic fields, including statistics for individual campaigns and campaign hierarchies
> 3. Merge fields for auto-number or compound address fields such as Mailing Address

I tried to refer the lookup field in the validation rule of an object and I was able to validate whether the lookup is blank or not and show an error if the lookup field is blank. I don't understand what it means by

> Validation rule formulas don’t or can’t refer to Compound fields,
> including addresses, first and last names, and dependent picklists and
> lookups

from the documentation link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it for some formulas such as isblank.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_limitations.htm

> The only formula functions that you can use with compound fields are
>   ISBLANK, ISCHANGED, and ISNULL. You can’t use BLANKVALUE, CASE,
>   NULLVALUE, PRIORVALUE, or the equality and comparison operators with
>   compound fields. The equality and comparison operators include = and
>   == (equal), <> and != (not equal), < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal), >= (greater than or equal), && (AND), and ||
>   (OR).

Seems a disconnect in the documentation

Comment: Thanks. Does the same apply for lookup fields also?

Comment: Yes as the previous info you posted says a lookup is a compound field and based on you trying it and it works

Comment: Makes sense. since lookup fields can't be used for any kind of computation or comparison. It can only be checked if it is blank or null.